# merged merge sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I had to write a merge sort function in Java. No problem. Well, a little, but I got through it. Then the follow up question I didn't get.

Question: Given an array `A[][]` such that `A[i][0]` is a `float` and `A[i][1]` is a nonnegative `int` giving the multiplicity of the value `A[i][0]` (here think of a big vector that's been collapsed down by combining repeated entries and recording how many got combined), write a version of merge sort that returns `B[][]` where `B[i][0] < B[i+1][0]` for all `i`.

Any ideas? The best I could do was merge sort and then group the equal ones, but apparently you can do it all in one step.

Comment: Is this "multiplicity" thing part of the comparison?

Comment: "A[i][0] is a float and A[i][1] is an int"? I think not!

Comment: You should be using a data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strage question... and using different types in these arrays is just ugly *(personal point of view)*.

However, the most useful thing to do, is to rewrite your merge function with a [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).
This way you can sort using whatever property you want.
You would end up with a signature like `void merge(A[] arr, Comparator<? super A> comp)`.
By the way, the Java implementation of sort is a lot like this.

To solve your question you would call:

```
A[][] a = ...;
merge(a, new Comparator<A[]>() {
  int compare(A[] a, A[] b) {
    return ((Float)a[0]) - ((Float)b[0]);
  }
});
```